# pattern using xmllint command-line

Tags: xml, bash, xmllint

```
]$ xmllint --version
xmllint: using libxml version 20626
```

My xml file looks something like this:

```
<projects>
 <architecture name="ARCH1">
  <project label="StringA1" type="StringB1" state="StringC1"/>
   ......
 </architecture>
 <architecture name="ARCH2">
  <project label="StringA2" type="StringB2" state="StringC2"/>
  ......
 </architecture>
</projects>
```

For example, I would like to obtain the value `StringB2` given the condition `name==ARCH2` and `state==StringC2`. Is it possible using `xmllint` command line options, if yes, how ? Some examples will be beneficial.

I can extract these using `sed` or `awk` but that may not be a good solution.

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
xmllint --xpath '//architecture[@name="ARCH2"]/project/@type'
```

or if you just want the string and only the string:

```
xmllint --xpath 'string(//architecture[@name="ARCH2"]/project/@type)'
```

While testing this statement I realized, that the ubuntu (12.04) version of xmllint (20708) terminates with a segfault when executing this command. I cloned the most recent version from https://git.gnome.org/browse/libxml2/refs/ and compiled. Now the command above works.

Comment: `--xpath` isn't available in the version that I am using. Can you provide the `libxml` version that you are using ?

Comment: I'm using xmllint version 20708

Comment: thanks. I will upgrade to a newer version of `libxml` and then confirm your answer...

Comment: @iamauser Hmm, must admit that I had not tested this  before answering.. I now tested and got 'segmentation fault'.. try to get a newer version

Answer (score 4):

Try the following

```
xmllint --xpath 'string(///project[../@name="ARCH1" and @state="StringC1"]/@type)' data.xml
```

Version:

```
$ xmllint --version
xmllint: using libxml version 20900
   compiled with: Threads Tree Output Push Reader Patterns Writer SAXv1 FTP HTTP DTDValid HTML Legacy C14N Catalog XPath XPointer XInclude Iconv ISO8859X Unicode Regexps Automata Expr Schemas Schematron Modules Debug Zlib Lzma
```